# How to make a vertical css steps menu

Tags: css, menu

Is there any tutorial on how to make a vertical css steps menu , like this [Horizontal steps](http://codylindley.com/blogstuff/css/stepmenu/) but in vertical orientation

Answer (score 1):

This is CSS of that page.
If you remove `float:left` you do the job!

```
#mainNav li {
background-color: #EBEBEB;
background-image: url("images/navBtn.gif");
background-position: right top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
float: left; <!-- REMOVE ME! -->
height: 71px;
list-style: none outside none;
}
```